# Adding classes to parents (which are not directly above in tree)

Tags: jquery

I have a form with many fieldgroups. Each fieldgroup contains many divs. When the form is submitted, required fields are not populated and the form is returned with `.error` classes attached to the incomplete elements.

I would like to use jQuery to attach an `.error` class (or inline css as seen in the example below) to every fieldgroup which contains an element assigned the `.error` class.

**Markup**

```
<h3 class="field-group-format-toggler accordion-item"><a href="#">T-Shirt Size</a></h3>
<div class="field-group-format-wrapper required-fields">
  <label for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und">T-Shirt Size <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
    <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-2" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="1"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-2">S</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
    <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-3" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="2"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-3">M</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
    <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-4" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="3"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-4">L</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

You will see `.field-group-format-wrapper` is not a decedent of the h3. I can rewrite the markup, if needed, but would prefer to not have to do this.

**css**

```
.error {
border: 2px solid red;
}
```

**jQuery**

I have tried:

```
 $( ".accordion-item" ).find(".error").css( "border", "2px solid red" );
```

as well as experimenting with `.parents()` but can't seem to get my syntax right. Would jQuery consider these siblings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `find` didn't work is that the errors aren't inside `.accordion-item`, they're in a div *after* it.

Your best bet is probably to put the `.accordion-item` and `.field-group-format-wrapper` in a wrapper of some kind, so they're grouped together and you can just use [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) (to find the wrapper) and then [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) (to find the `.accordion-item`). For instance:

```
var accordionItemsWithErrors = $(".error").closest(".accordion-wrapper").find(".accordion-item");
```

Live Example:

```js
var accordionItemsWithErrors = $(".error").closest(".accordion-wrapper").find(".accordion-item");
accordionItemsWithErrors.addClass("accordion-error");
```

```css
.accordion-error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-wrapper">
  <h3 class="field-group-format-toggler accordion-item"><a href="#">Has Errors</a></h3>
  <div class="field-group-format-wrapper required-fields">
    <label for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und">T-Shirt Size <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
      <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-2" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="1"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-2">S</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
      <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-3" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="2"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-3">M</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
      <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-4" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="3"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-4">L</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion-wrapper">
  <h3 class="field-group-format-toggler accordion-item"><a href="#">Doesn't Have Errors</a></h3>
  <div class="field-group-format-wrapper required-fields">
    <label for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und">T-Shirt Size <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
      <input class="form-radio" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-2" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="1"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-2">S</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
      <input class="form-radio" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-3" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="2"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-3">M</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
      <input class="form-radio" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-4" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="3"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-4">L</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion-wrapper">
  <h3 class="field-group-format-toggler accordion-item"><a href="#">Also Has Errors</a></h3>
  <div class="field-group-format-wrapper required-fields">
    <label for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und">T-Shirt Size <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
      <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-2" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="1"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-2">S</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
      <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-3" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="2"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-3">M</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
      <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-4" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="3"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-4">L</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you can't do that, I'd probably search for `.error` and then use [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the `.field-group-format-wrapper`s they're in, then use [`prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to go to the previous sibling element (the `.accordion-item`), like this:

```
var accordionItemsWithErrors = $(".error").closest(".field-group-format-wrapper").prev();
```

You'll end up with a jQuery object (a set of elements) containing the `.accordion-item`s that have `.error`s in them, thanks to jQuery's set-based nature.

Live Example:

```js
var accordionItemsWithErrors = $(".error").closest(".field-group-format-wrapper").prev();
accordionItemsWithErrors.addClass("accordion-error");
```

```css
.accordion-error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="field-group-format-toggler accordion-item"><a href="#">Has Errors</a></h3>
<div class="field-group-format-wrapper required-fields">
  <label for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und">T-Shirt Size <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
    <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-2" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="1"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-2">S</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
    <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-3" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="2"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-3">M</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
    <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-4" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="3"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-4">L</label>
  </div>
</div>

<h3 class="field-group-format-toggler accordion-item"><a href="#">Doesn't Have Errors</a></h3>
<div class="field-group-format-wrapper required-fields">
  <label for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und">T-Shirt Size <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
    <input class="form-radio" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-2" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="1"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-2">S</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
    <input class="form-radio" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-3" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="2"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-3">M</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
    <input class="form-radio" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-4" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="3"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-4">L</label>
  </div>
</div>

<h3 class="field-group-format-toggler accordion-item"><a href="#">Also Has Errors</a></h3>
<div class="field-group-format-wrapper required-fields">
  <label for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und">T-Shirt Size <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
    <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-2" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="1"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-2">S</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
    <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-3" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="2"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-3">M</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-appl-tshirt-und">
    <input class="form-radio error" id="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-4" name="field_appl_tshirt[und]" type="radio" value="3"> <label class="option" for="edit-field-appl-tshirt-und-4">L</label>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But that's fragile, which is why I'd change the structure a bit.

Comment: T.J., 

'$(".error").closest(".field-group-format-wrapper").prev().css( "border", "2px solid red" );'

Works perfectly. Thanks so much!